# Show that the ratio of the distance $BD$ to $DC$ is $\gamma:\beta$

Tags: vectors, ratio

I'm struggling on the following question

[image]

My approach to the question is as follows:
The equation of line $BC$ is: $\lambda_1$**b**+$(1-\lambda_1)$**c**
The equation of line $AP$ is: $\lambda_2(\beta$**b**$+\gamma$**c**$)$, for scalars $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$

Hence the intercept of the two lines occurs when $\lambda_1$**b**+$(1-\lambda_1)$**c**$=\lambda_2(\beta$**b**$+\gamma$**c**$)$
i.e this would be the position of $D$, but then how can I go further to show that $BD:DC=\gamma : \beta$

Comment: You can extend (or contract) $AP$ to the point with vector $$\frac{\beta\bf b+\gamma \bf c}{\beta + \gamma}$$
show that this new point is indeed on $BC$ and so is in fact $D$.

Answer (score 0):

With your method, comparing coefficients of $\mathbf b$ and $\mathbf c$,
$$\begin{cases}
\lambda_1 - \beta\lambda_2 = 0\\
\lambda_1 + \gamma \lambda_2 = 1
\end{cases}$$
Solving the system of linear equations,
$$\lambda_2 = \frac{1}{\beta + \gamma}, \quad\lambda_1 = \frac\beta{\beta+\gamma}$$
If $\beta + \gamma \ne 0$, then
$$\begin{align*}
\vec {AD} &= \frac{\beta \mathbf b + \gamma \mathbf c}{\beta + \gamma}\\
\vec {BD} &= \vec {AD}-\mathbf b = \frac{\gamma }{\beta + \gamma}(\mathbf c-\mathbf b)\\
\vec {DC} &= \mathbf c - \vec {AD} = \frac{\beta}{\beta + \gamma}(\mathbf c-\mathbf b)\\
\end{align*}$$